# Why isn't local mount showing up in k3d?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3s, argo-workflows, k3d

I am running k3d version:

```
k3d version v5.6.0
k3s version v1.27.4-k3s1 (default)
```

I initiated a new single node cluster on my Mac by running the following:

```
k3d cluster create mycluster --volume /Users/gms/development/nlp/nlpie/biomedicus:/data
```

I then import my docker image into the cluster:

```
k3d image import b9 -c mycluster
```

I then spin up a deployment pod using:

```
  spec:
    containers:
    - image: b9
      volumeMounts:
      - name: workdir
        mountPath: /data
      imagePullPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: workdir
    hostPath:
      path: /Users/gms/development/nlp/nlpie/biomedicus
```

Which creates the deployment just fine, but when I ssh into the pod:

```
kubectl exec -it <pod name> -- /bin/bash
```

and look at the directory `/data` it's empty and not pulling in my local data.

Not exactly sure what the issue is, especially since I've successfully created the mapping in my cluster (from the JSON output from the k3d containers):

```
"Binds": [
            "/Users/gms/development/nlp/nlpie/biomedicus:/data",
            "k3d-mycluster-images:/k3d/images"
        ]
```

and from issuing `kubectl describe pod <pod name>`, the mapping is there as well:

```
Mounts:
      /data from workdir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-8mjmx (ro)

Volumes:
  workdir:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /Users/gms/development/nlp/nlpie/biomedicus
    HostPathType:
```

plus, if I create a file in the /data directory in the pod/container it does not show up locally.

One caveat is that I am defining the deployment spec in Argo workflows, but that should not be affecting the volume mount, since this works perfectly in k8s.

*NB*: the goal is to port this over to a multiple node k3s cluster, where the `hostPath` will point to a shared CIFS mount on our nodes.

Comment: A `hostPath:` volume picks data from whatever node the Pod happens to be running on.  This will only work if your cluster has only a single node, but in that case other tools like plain Docker might be easier to set up.  What's in this directory; can you build it into your image?

Comment: This is a single node cluster running on my Mac (I will update the above). I am testing this locally before porting my stuff over to a server running a single node k3s cluster. As for building it into the image, the short answer is no, since the spawned pod will be processing a bunch of local data, for which I will need to write back to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that k3d is running containers in containers, so when you have created cluster using

```bash
k3d cluster create mycluster --volume /Users/gms/development/nlp/nlpie/biomedicus:/data
```

Then in the deployment yaml you should have path from k3d container, so `volumes` should look like

```yaml
  spec:
    containers:
    - image: b9
      volumeMounts:
      - name: workdir
        mountPath: /data
      imagePullPolicy: Never
  volume:
  - name: workdir
    hostPath:
      path: /data
```

For testing purpose to verify it I used this one whole deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: workdir
          mountPath: /data
      volumes:
      - name: workdir
        hostPath:
          path: /data
```

Comment: By Jove! That was it!